# Can't access my store object from my component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vuex-modules

In my store module `/store/template.js` I have:

```js
const templateConfig = {
  branding: {
    button: {
      secondary: {
        background_color: '#603314',
        background_image: ''
      }
    }
  }
}

export const state = () => ({
  branding: {},
  ...
})

export const actions = {
  initializeStore (state) {
    state.branding = templateConfig.branding
  }
}
```

(`initializeStore()` is called when app initially loads)

I want to retrieve the branding the `branding` object in my component:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    branding: state => state.template.branding
  })
}
```

But when trying to `console.log()` `branding` I see this:

[image]

Why don't I simply see the `branding` object? (and what on earth is this?)

Comment: Is your module namespaced ?

Comment: Yes it's automatic with `Nuxt`. If I try to access `state.branding` I get `undefined` instead of the weird thing from the screenshot.

Comment: This is not automatic to my knowledge. I'm talking about this, just to be sure: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: Yes look: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always use a mutation to change state.  You can call one from your action:

```
export const mutations = {
  SET_BRANDING(state, payload) {
    state.branding = payload;
  }
}
export const actions = {
  initializeStore ({ commit }) {
    commit('SET_BRANDING', templateConfig.branding);
  }
}
```

---

What you're seeing with the observer is normal, and indicates that the `branding` object has been successfully mapped and accessed.

What you see is Vue's [`observable`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) object, which is how Vue implements reactivity.  Without this, there would be no reactivity, and you will see such a wrapper on all top-level reactive objects.  You can pretend it's not there.

Vue in fact applies this same "wrapper" to the `data` object internally to make it observable:

> Internally, Vue uses this on the object returned by the data function.

You won't see it on other reactive properties, but if they're reactive, they belong to some parent observable object.

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'` (already done I guess).

And then, you can write this

```js
...mapState(['branding']) // or ...mapState('@namespacedModule', ['branding'])
```

Still, why do you not simply put the state directly (with your `background_color`) rather than going through a Vuex action ?

If you want to keep it this way, do not forget to `await this.initializeStore()` in your component before trying to access the state.

Comment: If I do `...mapState(['branding'])` I'm getting `undefined`, if I do `...mapState('@namespacedModule', ['branding'])` I'm getting the same weird thing I mentioned!

Comment: The fact that he sees the observable means that the mapping is already working